# writing a model for existing mssql table Django

Tags: django, django-models

I've this tables in a mssql server:

**Table name:** Items
**Fields:**
ItemID - primarykey - integer
StorageLocation - varchar(100)

**Table name:** Inventory
**Fields:**
InvetoryID - primarykey - integer
ItemID - foreignkey - integer
sku - integer
QtyToList - integer

How can I tell to Django that ItemID is the ID field and it's also the PK ? (do I need to tell it also it's an integer field?)

What is the best way to model it in django.

Thanks in advance
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Item(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table='Items'

    item_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ItemID')
    storage_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='StorageLocation')


class Inventory(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table='Inventory'

    inventory_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='InventoryID')
    item = models.ForeginKey('Item', db_column='ItemID')
    sku = models.IntegerField()
    qty_to_list = models.IntegerField(db_column='QtyToList')
```

Model Field Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Model Meta Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help. Django can also reverse engineer your models from an existing schema: `$ python manage.py inspectdb > all_models.py`  Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using the '[inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/)' command, then you can modified the result as you want. Please visit the [inspectdb documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) for more details on it.
The documentation is quite helpful.

Comment: suselrd, the limitation with inspectdb command is that it does not support MSSQL databases.

Comment: @abnerh69 maybe you are (were) using an old version? I do have some "This field type is a guess." for rare things like timestamp fields in the DB, but otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste What `ENGINE` are you using? I'm using django-pyodbc-azure and I get no output

Comment: I'm affraid that information is lost @CalebMcNevin I think I ended up solving this some other way (or the problem was utterly unrelated)